# Flutter - How can i play Randoms video from YouTube using a special title

Tags: flutter, video-streaming

is it possible to add Randoms video to my flutter app from YouTube   using a specific  title
for example I want to display Randoms "Football" video in my app ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add youtube videos to Flutter applications through a variety of methods. [Refer This plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter)

For more info: [Refer this medium article](https://medium.com/nonstopio/add-youtube-player-to-flutter-app-51e822709225)

The plugin supports a variety of features like custom buffering progress indicator, custom progress bar, standard audio/video control configurations.

Let's take an example URL: *youtube.com/watch?v=123iamosum456*

The value after "v=" is the video ID of that particular video which you would need to provide.